# Is my SD card dead that it shows wrong size in fdisk and not writable? How did it happen?

Tags: sd-card

Suddenly one day the SD card in my Raspberry Pi went bad.

The card is 16 GB.

Now if I put it in any of my card reader and connect it to my Linux PC, `fdisk -l` shows the follows:

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 30.61 MiB, 32096256 bytes, 62688 sectors
Disk model: SD  Transcend   
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytesWelcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.36.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

Device does not contain a recognized partition table.
Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0x9b5b8885.

Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sdc: 30.61 MiB, 32096256 bytes, 62688 sectors
Disk model: SD  Transcend   
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x9b5b8885

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Syncing disks.
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Just wondering how is the Raspberry Pi able to break the card into such a state and is there anything we can do to fix it. - Is the card actually broken at hardware level?

---

This is not even writable. I tried to use `fdisk` and then `w` to create a new partition table as follows.

```
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.36.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

Device does not contain a recognized partition table.
Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0x9b5b8885.

Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sdc: 30.61 MiB, 32096256 bytes, 62688 sectors
Disk model: SD  Transcend   
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x9b5b8885

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Syncing disks.
```

But it reverted to the same "no valid partition table" state as before.

`dd if=/dev/zero` appeared to work but there was no effect on fixing anything. It also showed that it wrote apporx. 30 MiB.

Comment: Very likely your sdcard wore out and needs to be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Write a fresh image to the card with the Raspberry Pi Imager available [here](https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/).

If that does not work the SD card is broken.

As to what happened - no way to know.

Answer (score 0):

If the Raspberry Pi Imager fails the SD Card is almost certainly damaged.

If you see ONLY a 32Mb drive the SD Card is faulty. This has happened to me once, and a few others. I contacted Sandisk concerning this and it was replaced under warranty. This is apparently a known but rare fault.

If you run the [SD Card Formatter](https://www.sdcardformatter.com) and perform a full format (which takes quite a while - often > 15minutes, depending on size) you MAY then be able to install an image using Raspberry Pi Imager, but the problem may re-occur if the card is worn out.

Formatting using other tools is usually a waste of time as they don't fully erase the card.